# What is the definition and origin of the phrase "force the straits"?

Tags: meaning, phrases, expressions, phrase-origin

I've seen the phrase used often in information about the WWI Gallipoli campaign ("forcing the straits" or "force the Dardanelles").

I know what force means (power, or using power to attain a goal).
I know what a strait is (narrow passage between land masses).

But this particular construct eludes me, precisely. I've never heard it used until reading about Gallipoli today.

I can guess - it seems to mean to barrel your way through, or to attack, a strait.

https://www.deseret.com/2015/4/22/20563269/this-week-in-history-allied-forces-land-at-gallipoli

"Several attempts were made to force the strait..."

https://thestrategybridge.org/the-bridge/2015/4/24/the-battle-of-gallipoli

"...send a fleet to force the Strait..."

So does it mean to make your way through (a temporary state), or to take complete control (permanently)?

More to the inspiration of my question: the quotes do NOT say to force one's way *through* the strait. Simply, to "force the strait".

Comment: Can you provide some example paragraphs for us? What does the context of the phrase tell you?

Comment: Try looking up the following two words:  'strait' and 'force' (the verb).  Once you find what a 'strait' is, Wikipedia the word 'Dardanelles'.  You will then quickly what the two words have to do with each other.

Comment: Have you looked up the verb 'force' in dictionaries? To be fair, only nearby senses are in most dictionaries, for instance [Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/force): << **force** [verb] [with object]: 
If someone forces a lock, a door, or a window, they break the lock or fastening in order to get into a building without using a key.
_That evening police forced the door of the flat ..._ >> . [CD](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/force): << to use  ...

Comment: physical strength or effort to make something move or open:

_She forced her way through the crowd_ >> Here, 'force N' with N a suitable noun means 'force one's way through N [against opposition]'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

'Barrel your way through' is a nice synonym.

Perhaps [Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/definition/force) gets closest of all the freely available dictionaries to defining this usage:

> **force** verb [with object]:
>
> 1 Make a way through or into by physical strength; break open by
> force.
>
> - *the back door of the bank was forced*

But the direct objects in this usage are restricted. As [Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/force) says,

> **force** [verb] {sense 5} [with object]:
>
> If someone forces a lock, a door, or a window, they break the lock or
> fastening in order to get into a building without using a key.
>
> - *That evening police forced the door of the flat*

The following [Google 3-grams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=force+the+lock%2Cforce+the+straits%2Cforce+the+pass%2Cforce+the+valley&year_start=1920&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3) strongly suggest that DOs such as 'straits', 'pass', 'valley' are not unknown, they are rarely used in comparison with say the arguably less nebulous 'lock'.

[image]